# How do I start an RxJava chain conditionally with a Completable into a Flowable?

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2

How would I go about starting a chain with a `Completable` based on a condition?

I have the code below in `getThings()` which works, but it doesn't feel like correct usage of RxJava based on the examples I've seen. The content of `downloadThings()` and `getCachedThings()` doesn't matter for this example, but the return types do.

```
fun downloadThings(): Completable {
    ...
}

fun getCachedThings(): Flowable<List<Task>> {
    ...
}

fun getThings(): Flowable<List<Task>> {
   return if (condition) {
               downloadThings()
           } else {
               Completable.complete()
           }.andThen(getCachedThings())
}
```

My understanding of RxJava is lacking so I can't explain it well, but it looks like the condition is "outside" the stream.

Is there a more correct way to do this, or is the way I'm doing it alright?

Thank you.

Comment: So data can either **be** emitted or not, right?

Comment: Yes, it downloads something if the condition is true or does nothing if it's false.

Comment: Worth mentioning that it is kind of opinion-based question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Completable.create(...)` can be used here, so you can encapsulate data loading logic inside the flow.

```
fun getThings(): Flowable<List<Task>> {
    Completable.create {
        if (condition) { downloadThings() }
        it.onComplete()
    }.andThen(getCachedThings())
}
```

That's if it is about refactoring without logic corruption. Otherwise, it is considerable to analyze if [`Maybe`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Maybe.html) fits your logic.

Comment: Thanks, that works exactly as I wanted and makes more sense! I'll check if Maybe would fit better too.